# How to set default page of ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net

I need some help, I have purchased a domain and I am using visual studio to publish the website via FTP. It publishes successfully but when I go into the website I get the Directory Listing Denied error, and I am assuming that this is due to the fact that there is no home page because when I go the address and append /Page.aspx to the address it works fine.

Is there any way that I could set the default page for the website I am publishing to point to the default page?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this thread should rather be on serverFault...

Comment: is Page.aspx your default page? if that is true, then you may have to rename it to default.aspx.  There are list of files that IIS looks for when specific page is not specified - default.aspx is one of them.

Comment: @tunmise fasipe - thanks for the response! It has done the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy answer: rename your default page to `Default.aspx`.

Or, if you have access to IIS configuration settings, you can specify the [default documents](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/203/default-documents/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

YOU need to spesify what page you want to use as your default based on the iis Default Document

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to a ISP control panel where you can specify the default page.

They are usually the same pages in most ISPs:

- Default.aspx
- Index.aspx